# Current Employer Autocomplete Field

Tags: wordpress, profile, relationships

In drupal the webform integration module allows an autocomplete field where you can search to add an employer from existing contacts. On my wordpress site however i am trying to allow users to update their current employer but it is just giving a text field with no autocomplete.

Are profiles able to use an autocomplete field for current employer? If not what are my other options?

Answer (score 2):

There have been many discussions in past about this on old forum eg this [one](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=25375.0) which refers to this [extension](https://github.com/TechToThePeople/publicautocomplete) - which looks like it needs testing for 4.6