# Event Registration: Is there a way to lookup organization as user types?

Tags: civievent, organization

On our event registration pages, we ask applicants for their organization name.

Ideally, when they start typing the organization name, we'd like to present them with a list of organizations in our civiCRM instance, so as to avoid duplicate/typo/variations on organization name.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

CiviCRM 5.39.0 and Joomla Joomla! 3.9.28

Answer (score 1):

There are answers [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8060/current-employer-autocomplete-field) which reference this [extension](https://github.com/TechToThePeople/publicautocomplete) and a blog about it [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/allenshaw/more-control-for-current-employer-fields-in-public-forms)

(found via google for "civicrm "current employer" autocomplete"

hope that helps